# SQL select works in Management Studio, but not from website

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [tblstudentrakazot].studentid, firstname, lastname, tblRakezetSchedule.* 
FROM 
    tblRakezetSchedule 
INNER JOIN 
    [tblstudentrakazot] ON [tblstudentrakazot].scheduleID = tblRakezetSchedule.scheduleid 
INNER JOIN 
    tblstudents ON [tblstudentrakazot].studentid = tblstudents.studentid 
WHERE 
    scheduleday = datepart(w,convert(datetime,'21/2/2016',103)) 
    AND tblRakezetSchedule.rakezetID = 182 
ORDER BY 
    replace(scheduletimefrom, ':', '')
```

When run from SQL Server Management Studio, it works perfectly and generates 3 records.

When run from my VBscript app, I get no records

The issue seems to be in the filter that refers to the date `scheduleday = datepart(w,convert(datetime,'21/2/2016',103))` - when I comment that out, the query works.

Does anyone know what the issue can be?

I have tried playing with the date settings but that didnt change anything.
I have tried doing `CONVERT(int,scheduleday)` in the `WHERE`  - that didn't help either, as the `scheduleday` is already a number format field.
I have tried using `dw` in the datepart instead of `w` - also no change.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

The query works when I do `WHERE CONVERT(int,scheduleday) = 1`

Also - I see that `CONVERT(int,datepart(w,convert(datetime,'21/02/2016',103)))` correctly gives 1 too. Its just weird that 1 <> 1   even when they are both converted to `INT`

---

Here is my VBscript:

```
sql = "SELECT [tblstudentrakazot].studentid, firstname, lastname, tblRakezetSchedule.* FROM tblRakezetSchedule"
sql = sql & " INNER join [tblstudentrakazot] on [tblstudentrakazot].scheduleID = tblRakezetSchedule.scheduleid "
sql = sql & " INNER join tblstudents on [tblstudentrakazot].studentid = tblstudents.studentid"
sql = sql & " WHERE " 
sql = sql & " CONVERT(int,scheduleday) = datepart(w,convert(datetime,'" & cleanSQL(planneddate) & "',103)) AND "
sql = sql & "  tblRakezetSchedule.rakezetID = " & CleanSQL(x_rakezetID)
sql = sql & " ORDER BY replace(scheduletimefrom, ':', '')"
```

WHERE:

`x_rakezetID` = 182
and `planneddate` is a date variable in the format of `21/02/2016'

Comment: For the query which works, what is the value of `scheduleday` in the rows that are returned? (Also, are you absolutely sure you're pointing at the same database? :) )

Comment: Are you querying the *same* database? Are there any records in the production database with the scheduleday value you expect? Are you sure this is the problem instead of eg, an error?

Comment: Pass your date as parameter of appropriate type, don't use strings. Or convert it to YYYYMMDD format. By the way, can't you determine weekday on the client-side?

Comment: Please include your VBscript in your question.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, I can confirm it's the same database. the value of `scheduleday` is 1 (Sunday). Additional info added to the question.

Comment: @kneidels, catch your VBscript query in SQL Server Profiler (SSMS Menu - Tools)

Comment: @RuslanK. - looks like I don't have permissions for this :(

Comment: @kneidels, try it on your test DB, where you have admin rights

Comment: What does CleanSQL() do? Does the sql statement created in the VBScript match the one you wrote in the Management Studio?

Comment: @jim31415 - `cleanSQL()` remove singles quotes etc... The SQL query which is generated from the VBscript is exactly the one i pasted in the original question.

Comment: What do you intend your "w" to do? I don't see it listed as any of the valid [parameters to datepart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420(v=sql.110).aspx)? Also, [language settings will affect week number calculation](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44328/does-the-week-day-number-changes-according-to-localization-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `SELECT datepart(w,convert(datetime,'21/2/2016',103))` [will depend on your session's language settings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44328/does-the-week-day-number-changes-according-to-localization-in-sql-server) (which will depend on the user.) For example:

```
SET LANGUAGE German;
SELECT datepart(w,convert(datetime,'21/2/2016',103)) ;
```

...returns 7, whereas for English it returns 1.

I therefore suspect that you are using different users or at least different language settings when connection through SSMS versus through your application.

Comment: Thanks - this was it. I use `Current Language=British` as part of my connection string. and for that value `w` returns 7 instead of 1. i have `Current Language=British` set, so that my default dateformat is `dd/mm/yyyy`. I will try see if there is a language i can use where the date format is this, but the first day of the week is Sunday.  Thanks!