# Running 'SET' command in SQL, prior to SELECT

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720172/sql-select-works-in-management-studio-but-not-from-website/35744691#35744691), I need to add something like

```sql
SET LANGUAGE German;
```

before my `SELECT` query.
I am running the query in an ASP/VBScript web environment, which basically limits me, as far as I know, to a single query at a time.
If I run a query such as -

```sql
SET LANGUAGE German; SELECT.....
```

I get a no results message, because the 'data' returned is from the `SET` query and not the `SELECT` that follows it.

Is there anything that can be done to run the `SET` and the `SELECT` together in the ASP/VBScript environment?

UPDATE: 
As per Lankymarts suggestion:

```sql
set rs = SERVER.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.open sql, conn, 1, 2

Do While (rs.State = 0 Or rs Is Not Nothing)  // also tried: Do While (rs.State = 0 AND rs Is Not Nothing) 
 Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
Loop

do while not rs.eof
  response.write ...
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Now that the closed recordset issue is solved, I am still not getting rows from the main recordset. 
This is my VBScript code, below.
There are definitely results (because 21/feb/16 - was on Sunday, and i have matching records for this) - but they are not being displayed. In fact even displaying via SSMS sometimes i dont get the results - maybe its getting all confused with the language changes?

```sql
    sql = " SET LANGUAGE German; "
    sql = sql & " SELECT [tblstudentrakazot].studentid, firstname, lastname, tblRakezetSchedule.* FROM tblRakezetSchedule"
    sql = sql & " INNER join [tblstudentrakazot] on [tblstudentrakazot].scheduleID = tblRakezetSchedule.scheduleid "
    sql = sql & " INNER join tblstudents on [tblstudentrakazot].studentid = tblstudents.studentid"
    sql = sql & " WHERE CONVERT(int,scheduleday) = datepart(d,convert(datetime,'" & cleanSQL(planneddate) & "',103)) AND "
    sql = sql & " tblRakezetSchedule.rakezetID = " & CleanSQL(x_rakezetID)
    sql = sql & " ORDER BY replace(scheduletimefrom, ':', '')"

    response.Write("### " & sql)
    set rs = SERVER.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    rs.open sql, conn, 1, 2

    Do While rs.State = 0 And Not rs Is Nothing
     Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
    loop 


    do while not rs.eof 
       ' we now proceed to loop through the actual result recordset : studentid, firstname etc...
```

By the way - does the language remain in German after the query has run, or does it return to its default language?

I guess what i need here is a language setting whose default is dd/mm/yyyy (because of other legacy requirements in the system) and one that the `DATEFIRST` is Sunday (1).

**ALSO:**
I tried to make a stored procedure, as such:

```sql
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procListRakezetSlotsByDay] @planneddate nvarchar(10),  @rakezetID int

    AS
    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SET LANGUAGE German;

    SELECT [tblstudentrakazot].studentid, firstname, lastname, tblRakezetSchedule.* FROM tblRakezetSchedule
    INNER join [tblstudentrakazot] on [tblstudentrakazot].scheduleID = tblRakezetSchedule.scheduleid 
    INNER join tblstudents on [tblstudentrakazot].studentid = tblstudents.studentid
    WHERE CONVERT(int,scheduleday) = datepart(d,convert(datetime,@planneddate,103)) AND tblRakezetSchedule.rakezetID = @rakezetID
    ORDER BY replace(scheduletimefrom, ':', '')


    END
```

and then run it:

```sql
    DECLARE @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[procListRakezetSlotsByDay]
            @planneddate = N'28/2/2016',
            @rakezetID = 182

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

    GO
```

and here too, it returns no results - even within SSMS... 
I am VERY confused.  thanks to all who have helped so far.

Comment: maybe `SET NOCOUNT ON;`?

Comment: @Lamak So, `SET NOCOUNT ON;SET LANGUAGE German; SELECT...`?

Comment: well, I would try it, I'm not really sure if it works though, that's why I posted it as a comment instead of an answer

Comment: @Lamak - thanks, tried - it doesn't work

Comment: Normally as long as your commands are separated by semi-colon, ASP has no trouble issuing multiple commands.   I'm not familiar with SET Language.. maybe it needs a GO statement after it?

Comment: @TabAlleman The semi-colon isn't needed if you pass a newline character `vbCrLf` between commands. Actually [I take it back](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563(v=sql.110).aspx) - *"Transact-SQL statement terminator.Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version."*

Comment: Why not create a stored procedure and call it a day? This way you can set your language, nocount, other session variables and run your query without issue in a single "command".

Comment: @JohnK - interesting idea, will give it a go

Comment: It would help if you [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35869099/edit) and post a code snippet showing the call you make in ASP/VBScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misconception. Neither ASP/VBScript limits you, the limit is imposed by the provider ADODB uses to perform the command. In terms of SQL Server though there is no limit *(I know of)* when executing a command that contains multiple queries.

First

```sql
SET LANGUAGE German;
```

isn't really a returning query but the Provider will return it as a closed `ADODB.Recordset` object, which isn't ideal but there is a simple fix.

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Will inhibit `DONE_IN_PROC` messages from being sent to say the executing line was successful which is interpreted by ADODB as a closed `ADODB.Recordset` object.

Another way to deal with this but not as straight-forward as [`SET NOCOUNT ON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189837(v=sql.110).aspx) is to use the [`NextRecordSet()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the `ADODB.Recordset` object to step through the various resultsets until you find the actual query result.

Assuming `rs` is our starting `ADODB.Recordset` object

```vb
Do While (rs.State = adStateClosed And Not rs Is Nothing)
 Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
Loop
```

will return the first `ADODB.Recordset` object that isn't in the closed state.

> <sub>From [MSDN - NextRecordset Method (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)</sub>
>
> *As long as there are additional results and the **Recordset** containing the compound statements is not disconnected or marshaled across process boundaries, the **NextRecordset** method will continue to return **Recordset** objects. If a row-returning command executes successfully but returns no records, the returned **Recordset** object will be open but empty. Test for this case by verifying that the [BOF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675787(v=vs.85).aspx) and [EOF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675787(v=vs.85).aspx) properties are both **True**. If a non–row-returning command executes successfully, the returned **Recordset** object will be closed, which you can verify by testing the [State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675068(v=vs.85).aspx) property on the **Recordset**. When there are no more results, recordset will be set to Nothing.*

Comment: Thanks Lankymart for your detailed suggestion.  This is the error I am getting using the code you suggested: `Object variable not set` referring the `DO` line. 
I didnt understand the 1st suggestion about the `SET NOCOUNT ON` - someone suggested that above, and it didnt help in the way it was suggested.

Comment: @kneidels That is just a code snippet you would need to have a `ADODB.Recordset` object instantiated and called `rs` for that to work. I assumed you must already be doing that somewhere in your ASP/VBScript code?

Comment: @kneidels and is that not working you still getting `Object variable not set`?

Comment: @kneidels Apologies haven't tested it *(pseudo coded)* think the `Or` should be an `And` updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, changed to `AND` and still getting the error

Comment: @kneidels My brain isn't working today that's invalid syntax which is why you get the weird `Object not set` error, it should be `And rs Not Is Nothing` you can't have `And rs Is Not Nothing` although it makes more sense if you say it out loud. What I get for not testing my code.

Comment: @kneidels Just tested it myself with different datasets and even notice I'm getting Driver Error messages returned in German *(when I specify my query wrong)* so `SET LANGUAGE German` is definitely working.

Comment: Thanks. This is weird: on `Do While rs.State = 0 And rs NOT IS Nothing` i am getting aVBscript error `Expected statement` pointing at the `NOT`

Comment: @kneidels I'm having a nightmare today I've edited the answer but given the wrong advice in the comment, sorry about this it should be `And Not rs Is Nothing` like the answer. The `Not` has to be separate from the `rs Is Nothing` comparison because it is checking for the `False` condition of `rs Is Nothing`.

Comment: thanks for your perseverance. One the line `Set rs = rs.NextRecordset` i now get a new error: `Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.`

Comment: @kneidels yeah that is due to the provider you are using probably `sqloledb` to properly support multiple step OLE DB operations use the [SQL Server ODBC Driver](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/) or better yet the [SQL Server Native Client 10.0 ODBC Driver](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-10-0-odbc-driver/) *(depending on the SQL Server version you might need a specific driver version)*

Comment: Thanks again. The ODBC option gives me and `Data source name not found` error, and the Native 10 seems not to be installed - I have asked the host if they will install it, and then I'll report back. (Am using MSSQL Version 2012)

Comment: @kneidels it's probably [SQL Server Native Client 11.0 ODBC Driver](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver/) if it's SQL Server 2012

Comment: Thanks, tried that too. same errors   :-(   Does that make sense??

Comment: @kneidels not really I've tested it with the SQL Server ODBC Driver connection string and it works fine. Tested the `sqloledb` one and got the same error as you. The connection string I used looks like `Driver={SQL Server};Server=...;Database=...;User Id=...;Password=...;`.

Comment: Great - this driver seems to work. Though i don't see it still going through the multiple recordsets. Am playing with it now to see.

Comment: @kneidels It's likely fixed the closed recordsets issue so you'll only see the loop code work if you pass more then one query that results in an open recordset.

Comment: You are right, it should... but it doesn't .. I have updated the question  (look for **UPDATE 2**) with my quesy and VBScript  code - and then as well with a Stored Proc i tried to use.